# Where does an app / website hold its data?

Tags: database, web-applications, relational-database, web-development-server

For a small start-up mobile app/website what options are there for storing its data? I.e. Physical server or cloud hosted data base such as azure.

Any other options or insight would be helpful thank you!

**Edit:**
For some background I'm looking at something that users could regularly upload data to and consumers could query to find results through an app or website.

Comment: Personal opinions are off-topic for Stack Overflow.  And opinions based on this question would be entirely wild guesses and pretty much useless to you anyway, since nobody here knows anything about what you're intending to build.

Comment: Hi I've made it less opinion based and given some background.

Comment: So... What exactly is your question?  Are you asking how to store data where internet users can access it?  Any internet-hosted database server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it depends on your work load and also on the your choice of data store. Generally, SQL based storage are costlier on cloud based solution due to the fact that those can be only vertically upgraded whereas no-sql ones are cheaper.
So according to me you should first decide on your choice of data-store, which depends on following factors:

1. The type of data; is your data structured or it falls under non-structured category?
2. Operations that you will perform on the data. Do you have any transactional use-cases?
3. Write/Read pattern; is it a read heavy use case or a write heavy one ?

These factors should help you decide on an appropriate data-store. Each database has its own set of advantages and disadvantages. The trick is to choose one based on your use cases and above mentioned factors.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm not sure about non-structured vs structured. Use cases could include Business A uploading data about there business on a weekly/monthly basis, and hundreds of other businesses are doing the same, but thousands of consumers are querying that data every day, perhaps marking which of those businesses is there favorite etc.

I suppose in that sense it would be read heavy but both functions would have to perform well overall.

Comment: yes it is definitely read heavy then. Now only question is do you require any transactional support? If not, it perhaps qualifies to be a no-sql data, of-course your type of data is not known to me yet. Also I foresee that your data may grow fast, considering how much of history you would like to maintain etc. Based on these and with limited insight of your use-case it seems no-sql could be an option for sure.